# Openshift creating too many processes

Tags: python-3.x, docker, openshift, gunicorn

[image: ps aux | grep "gunicorn" yields this]

I have a python application running using gunicorn. I have wrapped it in a docker image and deployed it on openshift. However, the pod either consumes too much memory or crashes with OOM/out of memory error.

On investing, I found out that there are multiple instances of my app being made even if I haven't specified gunicorn to create multiple workers.

Note: when the same docker image is ran on local machine, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Whose image are you using? If you are using the Python S2I image provided by OpenShift to wrap your application and haven't taken control of WSGI server execution and are letting the OpenShift image configure it, it will set the number of processes based on available resources detected. If your web application is particular memory hungry though and uses more than a typical application, the number of processes it creates may be too much. In this case you can set the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` concurrency environment variable to override how many process it sets.

See `WEB_CONCURRENCY` in:

- https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/blob/master/3.6/README.md

Comment: I am using a custom made image based on Ubuntu. I am pulling the image from repo and deploying it